# Why is Regex and StringBuilder slower at removing white space?

Tags: c#, regex, replace, stringbuilder, removing-whitespace

We are in the processing of integrating communication with an external API. It's been a bit of a headache so far due to inconsistent naming, poor documentation, and unreliable response/error messages.

One of the things we are dealing with is that certain Requests we send out to them have limits on the length of strings. Nothing groundbreaking but any Request that contains any string that exceeds the length requirements is just denied and fails.

Our solution has been to create an extension method for string that just takes in the maximum length and return a substring of that length starting at index 0.

I'm a junior dev and this is my first job, so I know my solutions are quite possibly not the most elegant or efficient. Either way, I raised the point that with our current extension we could end up removing pertinent information while including potentially worthless white space since we were not trimming or doing anything to check for double spaces etc. My lead told me to feel free to make an overload of the extension that would allow you to opt for removing white space as well.

I've come up with 3 solutions that completely remove any double spaces. I'm aware that the Regex method is the only one that truly removes all the white space, where as the other two are removing any occurrence of two spaces back to back. However this site will be solely used in the US, so I'm not sure if the extra time of the Regex is warranted.

My main interest in posting this is I'm wondering if someone can explain why my method using StringBuilder is so inefficient compared to the other two, it's even slower than Regex, I expected it to be the quickest of the three. Any insight here is appreciated as well as a hint to what may be a better way than any of these I've come up with.

Here are my three extensions:

```
    public static string SafeSubstringSomehowTheQuickest(this string stringToShorten, int maxLength)
    {
        if (stringToShorten?.Length < maxLength || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringToShorten)) return stringToShorten;

        stringToShorten = stringToShorten.Trim();
        int stringOriginalLength = stringToShorten.Length;
        int extraWhitespaceCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < stringOriginalLength - extraWhitespaceCount; i++)
        {
            int stringLengthBeforeReplace = stringToShorten.Length;
            stringToShorten = stringToShorten.Replace("  ", " ");
            if(stringLengthBeforeReplace < stringToShorten.Length) { extraWhitespaceCount += stringToShorten.Length - stringLengthBeforeReplace; } 
        }

        return stringToShorten.Length > maxLength ? stringToShorten.Substring(0, maxLength) : stringToShorten;
    }

    public static string SafeSubstringWithRegex(this string stringToShorten, int maxLength)
    {
        if (stringToShorten?.Length < maxLength || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringToShorten)) return stringToShorten;
        stringToShorten = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(stringToShorten, @"\s{2,}", " ").Trim();

        return stringToShorten.Length > maxLength ? stringToShorten.Substring(0, maxLength) : stringToShorten;
    }

    public static string SafeSubstringFromBuilder(this string stringToShorten, int maxLength)
    {
        if (stringToShorten?.Length < maxLength || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringToShorten)) return stringToShorten;

        StringBuilder bob = new StringBuilder();
        bool lastCharWasWhitespace = false;

        foreach (char c in stringToShorten)
        {
            if (c == ' ' && !lastCharWasWhitespace) { bob.Append(c); }
            lastCharWasWhitespace = c == ' ';
            if (!lastCharWasWhitespace) { bob.Append(c); }
        }
        stringToShorten = bob.ToString().Trim();

        return stringToShorten.Length < maxLength ? stringToShorten : stringToShorten.Substring(0, maxLength);
    }
```

Here is my quick test I'm using to compare time it takes for each extension to run:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

        string test =
            "   foo bar   foobar           f    oo        bar foobar      foofoo                                            " +
            "barbar    foo b  ar                                                                                       " +
            "   foo bar   foobar           f    oo        bar foobar      foofoo                                            " +
            "barbar    foo b  ar                                                                                       " +
            "   foo bar   foobar           f    oo        bar foobar      foofoo                                            " +
            "barbar    foo b  ar                                                                                       " +
            "   foo bar   foobar           f    oo        bar foobar      foofoo                                            " +
            "barbar    foo b  ar                                                                                       " +
            "   foo bar   foobar           f    oo        bar foobar      foofoo                                            " +
            "barbar    foo b  ar                                                                                       " +
            "   foo bar   foobar           f    oo        bar foobar      foofoo                                            " +
            "barbar    foo b  ar                                                                                       " +
            "   foo bar   foobar           f    oo        bar foobar      foofoo                                            " +
            "barbar    foo b  ar                                                                                       " +
            "   foo bar   foobar           f    oo        bar foobar      foofoo                                            " +
            "barbar    foo b  ar                                                                                       " +
            "   foo bar   foobar           f    oo        bar foobar      foofoo                                            " +
            "barbar    foo b  ar                                                                                       " +
            "   foo bar   foobar           f    oo        bar foobar      foofoo                                            " +
            "barbar    foo b  ar                                                                                       " +
            "   foo bar   foobar           f    oo        bar foobar      foofoo                                            " +
            "barbar    foo b  ar                                                                                       " +
            "   foo bar   foobar           f    oo        bar foobar      foofoo                                            " +
            "barbar    foo b  ar                                                                                       " +
            "   foo bar   foobar           f    oo        bar foobar      foofoo                                            " +
            "barbar    foo b  ar                                                                                       ";

        int stringStartingLength = test.Length;
        int stringMaxLength = 30;

        stopwatch.Start();
        string somehowTheQuickestResult = test.SafeSubstringSomehowTheQuickest(stringMaxLength);
        stopwatch.Stop();
        var somehowTheQuickestResultTicks = stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;

        stopwatch.Start();
        string regexResult = test.SafeSubstringWithRegex(stringMaxLength);
        stopwatch.Stop();
        var regexResultTicks = stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;

        stopwatch.Start();
        string stringBuilderResult = test.SafeSubstringFromBuilder(stringMaxLength);
        stopwatch.Stop();
        var stringBuilderResultTicks = stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;
    }
```

**Finally these are the results, the ticks vary a bit each run but the difference between the three methods is fairly consistent:**

All three return the same string of: "foo bar foobar f oo bar foobar"

somehowTheQuickestResult (method 1): **12840 ticks**

regexResult (method 2): **14889 ticks**

stringBuilderResult (method 3): **15798 ticks**

Comment: It would probably be even quicker if you worked with a character array, and moved the non white space ones over.. for bigger string comparisons you'd probably get very different results with your current methods

Comment: As a side note, all methods will return a string of lots of spaces unchanged even though it'd be too long.

Comment: For the regex, you probably want to exclude compilation time by creating an explicit `static readonly` instance of it with required [flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5845fdz(v=vs.110).aspx). For the stringbuilder, you probably want to pass `maxLength` as the [`capacity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1h0a5sy(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @GSerg not sure what you mean by your first comment? If the string is shorter than the maxLength then I just return it, because in that case I don't care about removing the white space. The purpose of removing the white space is for when the string exceeds the maxLength to allow as much pertinent info as possible to get passed with the request. So I think the first and last line in each method takes care of the issue you pointed out.

As for your second comment, thanks for the information, I will look into both those options and check the results!

Comment: @WRP If you pass a string that consists of a thousand spaces and nothing else, it will be returned unchanged. `stringToShorten?.Length < maxLength` will be `false`, `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringToShorten)` will be `true`, `false || true` is `true`.

Answer (score 5):

You're doing your benchmarking a bit wrong.

First, you need to "warm things up" and let JIT do its job. Basically, just call your three methods and discard the results.

Next, single try is not representative. Try average (or median time) over 100 or more iterations.

Third, your usage of `Stopwatch` is wrong. `Start()` after `Stop()` resumes interval measurements. `Restart()` is the way to go. With it, my tests show the following results:

```
9569
314
58
```

So, `StringBuilder` way *is* actually the fastest one.

Comment: Great catch! Sorry this is the first time I've utilized the Stopwatch. Going to work on redoing this and getting a better average over several thousand cycles.